# Spring boot csrf filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I was trying to enable csrf filter for some specific api calling and for the others no need of csrf filter.What I have done is

```
@Override

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    http.csrf().disable().addFilterBefore(new StatelessCSRFFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll();
}
```

The problem is when I was calling localhost:8080/public/hello

An error was showing

"message": "Missing or non-matching CSRF-token"

I am using Spring boot and Spring Security.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
http.antMatcher("/public/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
http.antMatcher("/rest/**").addFilterBefore(new StatelessCSRFFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).csrf().disable();
```

Or you can do like this.I think both will be working.

```
http.antMatcher("/public/**").csrf().disable();
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
http.antMatcher("/rest/**").addFilterBefore(new StatelessCSRFFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).csrf().disable();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `http.csrf().disable()` to `http.antMatcher("/public/**").csrf().disable()` and `http.antMatcher("/rest/**").csrf().disable()`. You will likely have to put those two lines each in their own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

That will tell Spring-Security to create multiple HTTP Security Filter Chains (akin to having multiple `<http/>` blocks in the XML model).